# Making a request to the Google Analtycis API responds with Login Required

Tags: python, google-analytics, google-oauth, google-analytics-api

I get data from the Google Analytics API v3

```
https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga:181335694&metrics=ga:sessions&start-date=7daysAgo&end-date=today
```

Once I run the browser is throwing an error

```
{
   "error":{
      "errors":[
         {
            "domain":"global",
            "reason":"required",
            "message":"Login Required",
            "locationType":"header",
            "location":"Authorization"
         }
      ],
      "code":401,
      "message":"Login Required"
   }
}
```

How to resolve this error?

Once I run python code I get the Google Analytics api, but I run in browser is throwing error for login is required how to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of data when we are talking about Google APIs.

Public data data that is not owned by anyone and everyone can look at 
Private data which is owned by a user and you must have permission to access it.

> "Login Required",

Means exactly that you must be authenticated in order to access the data you are trying to access.  You need the permission of the owner of that data.  You cant just take that get string and kick it off in a browser you need an access token in order to do that.   You get an access token from the authentication flow.

Since you mentioned python you should be following the [hello analytics tutorial](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/installed-py)  which will show you how to set up your project and authenticate your script so that you can get access to the data you need.

```
import argparse

from apiclient.discovery import build
import httplib2
from oauth2client import client
from oauth2client import file
from oauth2client import tools


def get_service(api_name, api_version, scope, client_secrets_path):
  """Get a service that communicates to a Google API.

  Args:
    api_name: string The name of the api to connect to.
    api_version: string The api version to connect to.
    scope: A list of strings representing the auth scopes to authorize for the
      connection.
    client_secrets_path: string A path to a valid client secrets file.

  Returns:
    A service that is connected to the specified API.
  """
  # Parse command-line arguments.
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
      formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter,
      parents=[tools.argparser])
  flags = parser.parse_args([])

  # Set up a Flow object to be used if we need to authenticate.
  flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(
      client_secrets_path, scope=scope,
      message=tools.message_if_missing(client_secrets_path))

  # Prepare credentials, and authorize HTTP object with them.
  # If the credentials don't exist or are invalid run through the native client
  # flow. The Storage object will ensure that if successful the good
  # credentials will get written back to a file.
  storage = file.Storage(api_name + '.dat')
  credentials = storage.get()
  if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
    credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, storage, flags)
  http = credentials.authorize(http=httplib2.Http())

  # Build the service object.
  service = build(api_name, api_version, http=http)

  return service


def get_first_profile_id(service):
  # Use the Analytics service object to get the first profile id.

  # Get a list of all Google Analytics accounts for the authorized user.
  accounts = service.management().accounts().list().execute()

  if accounts.get('items'):
    # Get the first Google Analytics account.
    account = accounts.get('items')[0].get('id')

    # Get a list of all the properties for the first account.
    properties = service.management().webproperties().list(
        accountId=account).execute()

    if properties.get('items'):
      # Get the first property id.
      property = properties.get('items')[0].get('id')

      # Get a list of all views (profiles) for the first property.
      profiles = service.management().profiles().list(
          accountId=account,
          webPropertyId=property).execute()

      if profiles.get('items'):
        # return the first view (profile) id.
        return profiles.get('items')[0].get('id')

  return None


def get_results(service, profile_id):
  # Use the Analytics Service Object to query the Core Reporting API
  # for the number of sessions in the past seven days.
  return service.data().ga().get(
      ids='ga:' + profile_id,
      start_date='7daysAgo',
      end_date='today',
      metrics='ga:sessions').execute()


def print_results(results):
  # Print data nicely for the user.
  if results:
    print 'View (Profile): %s' % results.get('profileInfo').get('profileName')
    print 'Total Sessions: %s' % results.get('rows')[0][0]

  else:
    print 'No results found'


def main():
  # Define the auth scopes to request.
  scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']

  # Authenticate and construct service.
  service = get_service('analytics', 'v3', scope, 'client_secrets.json')
  profile = get_first_profile_id(service)
  print_results(get_results(service, profile))


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Comment: I have doubt how to set json file path.get_service('analytics', 'v3', scope, 'client_secrets.json')

Comment: SystemExit: The client secrets were invalid: Missing property "redirect_uris" in a client type of "web". WARNING: Please configure OAuth 2.0

Comment: Make sure you downloaded the corect client_secrets.json file follow the tutorial on how to create it.  Make sure its in the same folder as the script you are running